Vectorization operation: TypeError -only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
I am using a function that inputs the start and the end index of an underlying numpy array to perform calculations on the subset of data. When inputting vectors for the start and the stop I keep getting this error:
def calculate_subset_results(start_dates, stop_dates, L):
    # Create index arrays for each combination of start and stop dates
    indices = np.arange(L.shape[0])
    start_indices = indices[start_dates[:, None]]
    stop_indices = indices[stop_dates[:, None]]
    
    # Slice the array L using numpy broadcasting
    subsets = L[start_indices:stop_indices]                     #HERE OCCURS THE ERROR
    # Perform calculations on the subsets
    results = np.sum(subsets, axis=1)  # Sum along the rows
    return results 


# Example usage
L = np.random.rand(100000)  # Example 1D numpy array
start_dates = np.array([0, 10000, 20000])  # Example array of start dates
stop_dates = np.array([5000, 15000, 30000])  # Example array of stop dates

subset_results = calculate_subset_results(start_dates, stop_dates, L)
print(L[20000])
"---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-199-c37a1aa71f54> in <cell line: 20>()
     18 stop_dates = np.array([5000, 15000, 30000])  # Example array of stop dates
     19 
---> 20 subset_results = calculate_subset_results(start_dates, stop_dates, L)
     21 print(L[20000])

<ipython-input-199-c37a1aa71f54> in calculate_subset_results(start_dates, stop_dates, L)
      6 
      7     # Slice the array L using numpy broadcasting
----> 8     subsets = L[start_indices:stop_indices]
      9     print(subsets)
     10 

TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
"


Do I need to change how I input the vectors, is there any trick? I would like to prohibit looping as I need to perform this a couple of times and would like to stick to vector operations.
I would like to input a vector to the function and receive a vector as an output.

Full error message please!  Maybe some debugging details as well.

In start_indices:stop_indices, only single values are allowed, not arrays.

Show some key intermediate values with scalar inputs.  Then show what you expect/want to happen with array inputs.

I added the full error message. Basically the function works well if I input 3 scalars. Now I want to perform this task a couple of times without looping. Therefore I would like to input 3 vectors and the nreceive a vector as a output. I thought that coulld be possible if you alter the input vectors

Are the start:stop slice (subsets) lengths all  the same, or can they vary? Or to put it another way, would an array of all subsets be rectangular (2d), or 'ragged'?

They are all the length. I think I found a solution. If you use do it like this, right: L[start[:, None] + np.arange(136)]

There are other SO like this, but  yes, usually the best thing is to create a 2d indexing array like this. np.linspace can also do this.  For just a few very long slices it still may be faster to iterate.

start_indices and stop_indices in this case must be integer and not scalar, here an example that explain more the error.
>>> L = np.random.rand(100000)
>>> L
array([0.88811571, 0.25921032, 0.36896352, ..., 0.15395515, 0.4545259 ,
       0.47172845])
>>> L[2000]
0.38937897690807544
>>> indices = np.arange(L.shape[0])
>>> L[indices]
array([0.88811571, 0.25921032, 0.36896352, ..., 0.15395515, 0.4545259 ,
       0.47172845])
>>> L[indices:indices]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
>>> L[indices[:5000]]
array([0.88811571, 0.25921032, 0.36896352, ..., 0.71316957, 0.81522261,
       0.63835866])


Hey, thank you very much. I want to have a row wise calculation of inputs and receive an output vector. How can I achieve this without looping?
